# How to stop setTimeOut via socket event?

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, settimeout, setinterval

I have a program where a Client can 'createTimer' via socket.io. The server then sends every second a time to all Clients which are in the same room.
When the Timeout reaches his maximum of repetitions, something happens on Client side because time = 0. So far so good. But in a special case, I have to clear the Timeout before it's done. But I don't know how to call clearTimeout. I have the same Problem with setInterval. Here is my Code:

```
socket.on('createTimer', data => {
 interval(function(){
  io.sockets.in(data.roomID).emit('newTime',{time:data.time--});
   }, 
 1000, data.time+1);
 })
 
 function interval(func, wait, times){
    var interv = function(w, t){
        return function(){
           if(typeof t === "undefined" || t-- > 0){
             setTimeout(interv, w);
             try{
                 func.call(null);
             }
             catch(e){
                 t = 0;
                 throw e.toString();
             }
           }
        };
   }(wait, times);
   setTimeout(interv, wait);
};
 
 socket.on('setTimerZero', roomID =>{
  // how can I use clearTimeout here? with which Timeout ID?
})
```

I'm thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: there are different Timouts running on the same time therefore I can't use a local variable for the Timeout ID

Answer (score 1):

You may store the timeouts per room, then you can clear them:

```
var timeouts={};
socket.on('createTimer', data => {
     setInterval(function(){
         io.sockets.in(data.roomID).emit('newTime',{time:data.time--});
     }, 1000, data.time+1,data.roomID);//pass it
})

function interval(func, wait, times,id){
    var interv = (function(w, t){
        return function(){
            if(typeof t === "undefined" || t-- > 0){
                timeouts[id]=setTimeout(interv, w);
                try{
                    func.call(null);
                }
                catch(e){
                    t = 0;
                    throw e.toString();
                }
            }
        };
    })(wait, times);//better with parenthesis
    timeouts[id]=setTimeout(interv, wait);//store it
}

socket.on('setTimerZero', room =>{
    if(timeouts[room.roomID]) clearTimeout(timeouts[room.roomID]), timeouts[room.roomID]=null;//clear if they exist
})
```

Comment: I've tried it just like that. Due to a console.log in 'setTimerZero' I see that this event is called right but the time just keep running. The Timout doens't stop.

Comment: @mcAngular2 you may not try *like that* but right *as that* ... i cannot do anything for things you havent overtaken from my code...

Comment: I certainly adjust it to my variable names ;)

Comment: I don't get it why it seems like 'clearTimeout' works, but the Timeout keeps running until 'times' = 0